# General linear groups and the axiom of choice

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, axiom-of-choice

In models of Zermelo-Fraenkel without the axiom of choice (AC), it is consistent to say that there exist vector spaces $V$ with bases of different cardinalities, say $B$ and $B'$. Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $k$.

Considere the general linear group $G = \mathrm{GL}(V)$ of $V$ (which consists of invertible linear transformations). Suppose $\vert B \vert = \omega$, and $\vert B' \vert = \omega'$ (where both $\omega$ and $\omega'$ are not finite). If we represent $G$ relative to the base $B$, we obtain $\mathrm{GL}(\omega,k)$ and if we do it relative to $B'$, we obtain $\mathrm{GL}(\omega',k)$.

I might be abusing notation here, but if not: I guess this means that in this model, $\mathrm{GL}(\omega,k) \cong \mathrm{GL}(\omega',k)$, while $\omega \ne \omega'$?

Comment: In this case $\omega^\omega=(\omega')^{\omega'}$, and so there's no reason for the isomorphism not to hold. Of course, $\omega$ and $\omega'$ cannot be well ordered, since, you know, AC.

Comment: Please **never** use $\omega$ in a set theory context, except to mean the first infinite ordinal. Please!